# How do I return JSON such that it can be accessed using dot notation?

Tags: python, json

Everything outside of the function must remain untouched.

```
def myFunction(jsonData):
    # do something with jsonData then return it.

def main():
    myJSON = [{"question":"What day is it?", "answer":"Monday"}]

    foo = myFunction(myJSON)

    print(foo.question, foo.answer)
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with program source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Is your question how to create an object in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dataclass

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Question:
  question:str
  answer:str

def myFunction(jsonData):
  return Question(**(jsonData[0]))

def main():
  myJSON = [{"question":"What day is it?", "answer":"Monday"}]

  foo = myFunction(myJSON)

  print(foo.question, foo.answer)
  
main()
```

output

```
What day is it? Monday
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the very simple and possibly naive custom dict implementation that equates attribute with key lookup:

```
def myFunction(jsonData):
    class AttrDict(dict):
        __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    return AttrDict(jsonData)

# not a list! Otherwise, how do you know the how manieth question to access
myJSON = {"question":"What day is it?", "answer":"Monday"}  
foo = myFunction(myJSON)
print(foo.question, foo.answer)
# What day is it? Monday
```

Comment: `myJSON` is a list

Comment: As I stated in the comment, that doesn't make sense in the context of the question. What if there is more than one dict? What could `foo.question` possibly be? Also, just apply the function to  `myJSON[0]` if it's a singleton. That is definitely better than writing a function that can do stuff to the first elemnt of a list :/

Comment: Defining an `AttrDict` this way means that you won't get auto completion or type hints from an IDE about what `foo` contains, and imo that's something that is generally preferable.